# Specific version of library is not available

Tags: 14.04, apt, versions, openssl

I have two ubuntu ec2 instances as below.

Instance 1:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Instance 2:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I am trying to install `openssl` with version `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.2`. It is successfully installed on `Instance2` but not working on `Instance1` because the version is not available.

Thing is I did an upgrade on Instance1 by mistake and it updated ubuntu to `14.4.2`.

I would like to know how to install that version on the Instance1 or If there is a way to go back to the previous version so that the version installs successfully on it.

Answer (score 0):

To install `version 1.0.1f` if it is missing from your repos after an upgrade you can install it with this deb file

For 64bit

```
wget archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i openssl_1.0.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

For 32bit

```
wget archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1f-1ubuntu2_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i openssl_1.0.1f-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

Or find the downloads for may linux versions [here.](http://pkgs.org/download/openssl)

Comment: That works, but I have to do it using salt-stack so there should be no manual intervention. I am confused why the lib is there for 14.4 but not for 14.4.2?

Comment: Guess it was just updated in 14.04.2, thats the point of `lts` too make security and package updates, please accept the answer with the tick on the left if it worked for you, if you had to take extra steps please fell free to edit the answer, as I am no familiar with `salt-stack`